# Why does JavaFX ImageView sometimes require BufferedImage to display anything?

Tags: javafx, imageview

Currently trying to implement a warning graphic to place next to an input field.

Dropped the ImageView into Scene Builder, located the file, generated:

```
    <ImageView fx:id="helpPic" fitHeight="22.0" fitWidth="33.0" layoutX="47.0" layoutY="336.0" onMouseClicked="#warnInfo" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
       <image>
          <Image url="@../../Library/risk-468289_640.png" />
       </image>
    </ImageView>
```

No errors on loading, but no image.

I'm trying to then load it as part of the controller:

```
helpPic.setImage(new Image("Library/risk-468289_640.png"));
```

No errors, still no image.

To verify that it's not the image, I scribbled something up in mspaint as a jpg and tried to load that and it still does not display anything.

Looking for a solution, I got it working via:

```
BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new File("Library/risk-468289_640.png"));
Image image = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(bufferedImage, null);
helpPic.setImage(image);
```

But it seems extremely odd that the FXML/ImageView requires additional handling to do its one job.

EDIT:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MainWindow.fxml"));

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.resizableProperty().setValue(Boolean.FALSE);
    stage.show();
}
```

Comment: You are on Windows, Linux or Mac?

Comment: The `javafx.scene.image.Image` constructor expects the string version of a valid URI. Does `helpPic.setImage(new Image(new File("Library/risk-468289_640.png").toUri().toString()));` work? For the FXML version, I have to check this, but I think `..` can't be interpreted in that context (it makes sense if everything's on a file system, but once everything is bundled into a jar file it can no longer form a valid URI). If I get time, I'll experiment with how to do that an post a real answer (if no-one else does first).

Comment: The original case is provided by Scene Builder from a file chooser dialog.  I'll try the code in a bit and see if it works.  That seems kind of dumb to me, though.  If a file can be identified as existing at the location specified in the file, shouldn't the file contain the necessary information for anything accepting a file to parse it.  And, if not, shouldn't it throw something?

Comment: Yes, it should throw an exception. So maybe I am barking up the wrong tree and something else is wrong. Let me test out the `@` resource location resolution with parent directories.

Comment: Not that you can edit it at this point, but toURI not toUri, however it seems to work.

Comment: I tested with the same mechanism you used, using SceneBuilder and selecting the file using the file chooser; it worked fine for me. I guess: check the deployment folder that your IDE generates (`bin` or `classes` or somesuch, depending on your IDE: the one with the class files, not the java files) and make sure the image is being exported to that folder. (The point being, the url is being resolved relative to the class file, not the java file.)

Comment: And I had one other idea: can you post the code where you call `load(...)` on the `FXMLLoader`. (FXML URL resolution will not work if you call the `load` method that takes an `InputStream`; you must provide a `URL` to the loader somewhere.

Comment: The Library folder is sibling to both of them, so it shouldn't matter... Though I was having this problem a lot prior to the front end, so I don't know what changed.

Comment: @James_D I just got your question now, I'll edit it into the question.

Comment: "The Library folder is sibling to both of them". To me that implies that `Library` is not part of the classpath - is that right? Resource location resolution won't work if you move outside of the classpath (anything that works must still work when you package the application as a jar file, for example).

Answer (score 0):

I can't quite figure out why the FXML version is not working for you, but I can give you a description of how that works, which should be enough for you to figure out what is going on.

When the `FXMLLoader` encounters an attribute value beginning `@`, it treats it as a resource location and resolves it to a URL as stated in the [FXML documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#location_resolution). What this basically means is that it generates a `URL` by calling

```
new URL(location, spec);
```

where `location` is the location property of the `FXMLLoader` and `spec` is the attribute value with the leading `@` stripped off. This resolves according to the rules described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#URL-java.net.URL-java.lang.String-).

The `location` property of the `FXMLLoader`, in turn, is the value you pass either to the [`FXMLLoader` constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#FXMLLoader-java.net.URL-), [`FXMLLoader.setLocation(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#setLocation-java.net.URL-), or the `static` [`FXMLLoader.load(...)` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#load-java.net.URL-).  In your case you create this URL with `getClass().getResource("MainWindow.fxml")`. I always think of this as meaning "get a URL which loads the resource from the same place as you loaded this class": obviously that is somewhat of an informal definition, the precise description is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource-java.lang.String-). Roughly speaking, what will happen is that if the string you provide does not begin with a `/`, the resource will be searched in the same package as the class; otherwise it will (usually) be searched in the classpath. The scheme of the URL *depends on the class loader associated with the current class*. So if you are running your application from the file system, the actual URL will look like `file:///path/to/current/package/MainWindow.fxml`. If you are running from a jar file it will look like `jar:///path/to/jar/file!/package/MainWindow.fxml` (or something like that), where `package` is the package in which your class is defined, with the `.` replaced by `/`.

So if the `location` property of the `FXMLLoader` has a `file:` scheme, things should basically work (assuming the file is in the right place). You essentially do

```
new URL("file:///path/to/current/package/MainWindow.fxml", "../../Library/risk-468289_640.png");
```

(the first argument is really an existing `URL` object not a `String`). Since the `file:` scheme can happily understand the parent directory symbol `..`, things should work appropriately.

On the other hand, if your class was loaded by a jar class loader, things might break:

```
new URL("jar:///path/to/jar/file!/package/MainWindow.fxml", "../../Library/risk-468289_640.png");
```

If you have more parent directory levels here than package levels, the jar class loader won't be able to create anything meaningful. (The `jar:` scheme means "load from the jar file", but you are trying to jump out of the top level of the jar file entry hierarchy.)

It sounds like you are trying to access a file resource which is outside the classpath: doing this with an FXML resource location is not really guaranteed to succeed, because it essentially tries to use the `ClassLoader` to load the resource, which in general only really knows about things in the classpath. Specifically, with a jar class loader, it is going to fail.

You can add some debugging in your `start` method to try to see what is happening:

```
URL fxmlURL = getClass().getResource("MainWindow.fxml") ;
System.out.println(fxmlURL.toExternalForm());
URL resourceURL = new URL(fxmlURL, "../../Library/risk-468289_640.png");
System.out.println(resourceURL.toExternalForm());

Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(fxmlURL);
```

This should at least let you see what the `FXMLLoader` is trying to do, and you should be able to see whether or not the resulting URL makes sense.

If you are loading the `Image` from the file system (rather than from the classpath), it's better to explicitly create a file URL (which you have to do in Java code, i.e. in your controller):

```
// path is relative to working dir: use an absolute path if needed
File imageFile = new File("Library/risk-468289_640.png"); 
String imageURL = imageFile.toURI().toURL().toExternalForm(); 
helpPic.setImage(new Image(imageURL));
```